# Apache Sling on IBM Bluemix

Tags: apache, docker, cloud, ibm-cloud, sling

does someone ever run Apache Sling on Bluemix? I am wondering how to do that. Is there any chance to just start a Sling instance as you would do using Docker? https://hub.docker.com/r/apachesling/sling/

Or do I need to run in on to of WebSphere?

If you have any hint for me, I would be thankful. I am also interested in other options to run an Apache Sling instance in the cloud somewhere.

BR
Tim

Comment: If a docker images is already available for sling, maybe you could deploy it in the ibm containers service: https://www.ibm.com/cloud-computing/bluemix/containers